# TabLayout - indicator animation is delayed

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

In my application I have TabLayout with two tabs: Stopwatch and Timer. When I switch between this two tabs and timer is not running then everything works great. Problem occurs when I start timer, indicator animation is delayed. Below video demonstrating this issue:

https://media.giphy.com/media/xjLnjaQ0NgH0a4yqsO/giphy.gif

I think this is caused by short countDownInterwal in CountDownTimer. I set this to 50. This value is low because I want to have smooth time indicator (in my app blue big circle - [Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEfSh.png)).

```
private void startTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                mProgressBar1.setProgress((int) (timeLeftInMillis/10));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                finishCountDownTimer();
                countDownSound.start();
                showDialogWhenFinishCountDown();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

What sould I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CountDownTimer` is not an optimal solution (for a start the entire class is `synchronised` which causes immediate overhead), you shouldn't be animating this manually if you want smooth animations.  Use what the Android Framework has to offer.

I used `ObjectAnimator` with a very quick example :

[Example Animation](https://imgflip.com/gif/2sgcz4)

Basic Fragment class - what you'll be most interested in is the `startStopTimer()` method :

```
public class TimerFragment extends Fragment {

    public TimerFragment() { }

    private static int ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS = (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ObjectAnimator animator;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);
        progressBar.setProgress(ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startStopTimer();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startStopTimer() {
        if(animator == null) {
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS, 0);
            animator.setDuration(ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);
            animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animator.start();
        } else {
            animator.cancel();
            animator = null;
            progressBar.setProgress(ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if(animator != null) {
            animator.cancel();
            animator = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you :)